# IPTC Block -- commons-imaging

Tags: java, apache-commons

`org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.jpeg.iptc.IptcBlock` is not public in `org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.jpeg.iptc;` cannot be accessed from outside package

We started getting this error today after maven downloaded latest snapshot. What is alternative way to read the IPTC Blocks now

Looks like they made it private class.

FIXED: Apache have rectified and made class public again

Comment: Don't use snapshots? Ask the apache developers?

Comment: site where can I ask the apache developers?

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/mail-lists.html

Comment: thanks. Let me check with them.

Comment: No reply from anyone @ Apache Developers.

Comment: No response: I don't know what you are doing wrong but there was a response on Tue 11th: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/commons-user/201610.mbox/browser

Comment: my bad I overlooked it. The issue is fixed by them. Thanks Robert for you guidance.